# How to solve "error running pod install" in flutter on mac?

Tags: ios, macos, flutter, dart, pod-install

I have an error when I tried to launch my project on my iPhone, the basic Flutter example is working on my iPhone but when I use my project I have this error.

[image]

Comment: Please post the error output as text and provide information about how to reproduce.

Answer (score 125):

In Flutter project, I Also faced with this issue. Fixed by updating flutter and cocoa pods to the latest version.

Solution:

```bash
flutter clean
rm -Rf ios/Pods
rm -Rf ios/.symlinks
rm -Rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework
rm -Rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec
flutter pub get
cd ios
pod install # (or on an M1+ mac: arch -x86_64 pod install)
cd ..
flutter build ios
flutter run
```

Comment: On an M1 mac, `arch -x86_64 pod install` may have to be used instead of `pod install`

Comment: I had to run `arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update`

Comment: Had to do the following:
`cd ios`, `rm Podfile.lock` and `arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update`

Answer (score 67):

You can fix it with

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
```

Comment: This resolved my issues on MacBook Pro M1. Thanks.

Comment: this seemed to fix my issue as well, just had to restart vscode after

Comment: Didn't work for me

Comment: What exactly does this do? Can you provide more information?

Comment: I having this issue from M2 itself. after I install the Google Fonts 6.1.0 version in my flutter projects, Don't have an idea about it.

Answer (score 30):

I got this error when I was using Firebase in flutter, the solution for me was to set the Podfile deployment target to a iOS version higher than 9.

Example:
Changed this

```
#platform :ios, '9.0'
```

to

```
 platform :ios, '13.0'
```

And as @Mana commented, remember the higher the version you set, your app will not be supported for users with lower IOS versions

Comment: Updated to 14.5 and works.

Comment: Same here,  with Firebase in flutter. changed platform to 13.0 also works with iOS 15.3

Comment: but pls remember the higher the version you set, your app will not be supported for users with lower IOS versions

Answer (score 22):

I faced the same issue and none of the above work. Finally I resolved it by:

1. Check `ios/.symlinks/plugins` contains extra plugin which you are not using.
2. Delete `podfile.lock` in ios folder, if it exists.
3. Delete `podfile` from ios folder.
4. Delete `pods` folder in ios directory.
5. Run `flutter clean` in the terminal.
6. Run `flutter pub get` in the terminal.
7. Run `flutter run`in the terminal.

Comment: Worked with me after I updated my cocoapods (pod) from 1.10 to 1.11.2

Comment: I followed your method and then ran `brew reinstall cocoapods` and it started working on M2 Pro 2022

Answer (score 17):

***2022 update***

After struggling for hours the following helped me:

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
brew install cocoapods
```

Make sure you have HomeBrew installed before you do the above. Steps to install HomeBrew: [Install HomeBrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66666134/how-to-install-homebrew-on-m1-mac)

Comment: Phew!! That did it.  Upgraded pod to 1.11.3.

Answer (score 7):

For Mac M1, try the following commands. Worked for me fine

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

Answer (score 6):

1. Change directory to your project; e.g `/dart/apps/abc`
2. Type, `flutter clean && pod update`

Comment: No `Podfile' found in the project directory.

Comment: Pod is located on `project/ios` folder, run `cd ios`

Comment: if no podfile, clean and pub get

Comment: 1) flutter clean
2) flutter pub get
3) cd macos or cd ios
4) pod update

Worked for me

Answer (score 3):

So did you solve this problem?

I met the same situation. And this is the solution I found.
[Link](https://armen-mkrtchian.medium.com/run-cocoapods-on-apple-silicon-and-macos-big-sur-developer-transition-kit-b62acffc1387)

Basically:

- Locate Terminal.app in Finder. (Applications->Terminal.app)
- Right-click and choose Get Info
- Check the “Open using Rosetta”
- Quit all instances of Terminal app and run it again
- Run sudo gem install ffi

After you finish the above several steps, restart your IDE and re-run the application.
Please give a reply if this method works.

Comment: Yes, "Run sudo gem install ffi" resolved the issue for M1 Mac. The terminal.app is located in (Applications->Utilities->Terminal). Right clicked Terminal, Get Info, and clicked the checkbox "Open using Rosetta". Then cd'd into flutter project, run flutter clean, flutter pub get, and flutter build iOS. This resulted in a "Building a deployable iOS app requires.." notice. Then app would run in iOS simulator. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using VS Code and flutter 2.10.1
running intel mac

I've faced this problem several times, usually when switching between projects or when working with multiple versions of project. But the solution is pretty simple.

1. Inside your project parent directory go to, ios -> Podfile. Here the top line will be something like this,

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'
```

check whatever version you are using on simulator and replace '9.0' with that and uncomment.

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '15.4'
```

2. Now if we try to run the flutter project, the debugger will say that the cocoapods are outdated. So just update them using command

```
pod repo update
```

And that should solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple reasons this could occur so a one-size-fits-all solution won't exist.

Instead, in terminal, run:

$`cd ios`

$`pod install`

This will give you more in depth information on the error and you can search from there. In my case one of my dependencies required a higher minimum ios version so I had to open the .xcworkspace file and adjust the minimum deployment version in xcode>targets>general>minimum_deployments

Comment: This should have more upvotes as there are a lot of things that could cause this issue, and this one will help troubleshoot

Answer (score 2):

1. Delete the `podfile.lock` (located in app root > ios folder)
2. Run in Terminal `pod install --repo-update`
3. `flutter run`

Comment: Did not work for me

Answer (score 2):

1. Simply delete the Podfile from your project
2. Run this command in terminal (I did in Android studio terminal it self)

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

3. And then run this

```
pod init
```

It works for me..

Answer (score 2):

The link https://cdn.cocoapods.org does not work correctly, I had to change the source in `ios/Podfile` as described in the code below:

1. Change source in `ios/Podfile`

```bash
# platform :ios, '9.0'

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
```

2. Clean your project

```bash
flutter clean
```

3. Install referenced packages

```bash
flutter pub get
```

4. Run the app

---

The error can also come from a package which requires a version higher than `'9.0'` in this case it is necessary to uncomment the line `# platform :ios, '9.0'` and to pass for example to version `'14.0'` according to the version requested by the package.

Answer (score 1):

For me none of the above helped, the following worked on my case:

1. Deleted the `macos` folder from main project.
2. Created a `dummy flutter project`.
3. Copied the newly created `macos` folder.
4. Pasted it to my `main project`.

Additionally I use firebase plugins, so I made some changes in `pod` file,..
It started running.

Answer (score 1):

Open Your Terminal paste this line of code open ~/.zshrc press Enter

if you don't have the zshrc file you will have to create it, to create it you need to open terminal paste this code  touch ~/.zshrc add you flutter path and move to Second instruction

2 The Text File will open add then you add this  export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to build flutter app in my M1 chip MacBook Air when I faced this issue, unfortunately the above solutions did not work for me but this did -

add to your ~/.zshrc or ~/.bashrc

```
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Reference - [CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding and it aborts to run pod](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6333#issuecomment-551052399)

Answer (score 0):

I'd the same problem, in my case when I ran `pod install --verbose` I realize that there was an specific error during `pod install`

> undefined method `each_child' for #Dir:0x00007ff10befa7f0 Did you mean? each_slice

Looking for this specific error I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65197799/flutter-pod-install-problem-undefined-method-each-child-for-dir0x00007fa6#answer-65617635) and I realize that I was using ruby 2.5 and one file generated by Flutter for iOS devices was trying to use a method that was introduced on version 2.6.

After follow the steps on that answer I could run my Flutter app on iOS simulator.

> The method `dir.each_child` [was introduced in Ruby 2.6](https://bigbinary.com/blog/ruby-2-6-introduces-dir-each_child-and-dir-children-instance-methods), but you are using Ruby 2.3.0.

> You should [update Ruby](https://codingpad.maryspad.com/2017/04/29/update-mac-os-x-to-the-current-version-of-ruby/) to 2.6.0 or later 2.x version.

> After Ruby updating you may also need to restart your IDE and [re-install cocoapods](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation).

Answer (score 0):

Check in ios/.symlinks/plugins for unused plugins. and if there are, remove from pubspec.yml. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

As per the install instructions make sure M1 users run. Solved the issue for me. I missed it on install!

```
$ sudo softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve the same issue so:

- Delete *podfile.lock* in iOS-folder app
- Run *pod repo update* in the terminal
- Re-compile my code

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems running flutter web on mac.
Make sure you uncomment and update the podfile from macos folder not ios
I'm talking about these lines:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :osx, '15.4'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an automated script to change the deployment target, use

```
sed -i '' 's/9.0/10.0/' ./.ios/Podfile
```

where 9.0 is the generated iOS version and 10.0 the desired

on your pipeline, shell script or whatever

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is struggling on M1 machines with a particular pod, the following helped me:

```
flutter precache --ios  
arch -x86_64 pod update Firebase/Firestore //or name of pod from the error
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error after install in_app_purchase: ^3.1.5 in flutter for macos

I solve :
Make sure that in podfile and target platform in runner the version are the same and minimum 10.14 , but maybe you try next versions for other packages error

from flutter_project_folder -> macos -> Podfile , in this file edit and first line usually "platform :osx, '10.XX'"  so change to "platform :osx, '10.14'"
and in xcode open macos folder in the flutter project , then in runner -> select the macos target to match as in Podfile , here i change bothed to 10.14 the version

check as below image in xcode :
[image]

and for Podfile :
[image]

Answer (score -1):

run this code on the terminal

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
```

Next, go to the ios folder in your project, and open Podfile.

Then change `#platform :ios, '9.0'` to `platform :ios, '10.0'`