# Can't run Flutter project in IOS Emulator getting :Error running pod install

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

Inside the IOS folder if I run pod init, I get: [!] Existing Podfile found in directory.
And then if I run pod install, I get: [!] No `Podfile' found in the project directory.

Comment: Can you show me the file list in ios directory using. ```ls -la```

Comment: Flutter, GoogleService-Info.plist,Podfile,Pods,Runner, Runner.xcodeproj,Runner.xcworkspace

Comment: Can you try these solution ```https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54135078/how-to-solve-error-running-pod-install-in-flutter-on-mac```