# I caught with pod installation error to open IOS Simulator on MAC environment and Unable to run Android emulator too

Tags: flutter, dart, cocoapods, ios-simulator

- [How to solve "error running pod install" in flutter on mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54135078/how-to-solve-error-running-pod-install-in-flutter-on-mac)
- I tried all methods from the above forum nothing resolved my problem.
- Please check this image for better overview of the problem [Pod Error pictorial information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObIFI.jpg)
- To run the application on android environment, stuck with the gradle task assembleDebug failed.
- Couldn't open Android Emulator on it.
- I didn't got any problems with code Output.
- Tried different methods to resolve the pod installation running error method for infinity loop.
- Tried reinstalling cocoapods and ruby softwares multiple times.
- Nothing resolved my issue by going though the following technilcal domains in order 1. StackOverFlow 2.Flutter Community 3. Geek for geeks and remaining technial blogs
- Reinstalled xcode application, flutter and dart by doing clean installation and tried various versions of packages to fix the pod error.
- I'm sharing the error bug with image details, please resolve my pod install error to test the main application in IOS simulator. [Pod Error pictorial information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObIFI.jpg)
- I'm expecting a resolution for this pod installation issue.